# Will activity down using request be reflected on my gmail?

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am working on a program that does a bunch of random stuff while logged in my gmail (using requests). I know how to login to gmail (thanks to previous questions asked here and a bunch of guides on the web). However I am concerned about the activity bit. If I login to my gmail and then did a GET request to a youtube video or go to, say Instagram. Will that activity be reflected on my history or be sent to Google?

Comment: Google owns Youtube. Of course Google will know about your Youtube video request. Whether they'll link it to your email depends on other details.

Comment: no ... `requests.get` is an entirely unique context... it has nothing to do with whoever you are logged in as in some browser ... but if you authenticate your request then they will definately know ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I'm pretty sure they're logging into Gmail through `requests`, not in a browser.

Comment: I dont think so ... they are using selenium to login im guessing ... with requests you pretty much have to use the provided APIs ... and even if they managed to login with requests... the next request wont have any of the session or cookie data unless you have explicitly created a request.session, or copied the cookies from the response ...

Comment: `logged in my gmail (using requests).` ... oops maybe not ... I think we need more information on what OP is actually doing (ie are they really just using the google apis?)

Comment: No I was intending on using requests to login. I assume logging in and just using requests.get(youtube_vid_here) won't work?